# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 Giving Following Exception on deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. and WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.0. When i deploy my project. WSO2 developer studio does not show any error and build and deployment is successful there but WSO2 ESB making the CAR file faulty and throwing the following exception.

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Sequence Deployment from the file : /home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/carbonapps/work/1425396583636WebShopOrderAdapterCA_1.0.0.car/ValidateIncomingRequest_1.0.0/ValidateIncomingRequest-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:211) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:100) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:251) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:114) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67) at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79) at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Sequence Deployment from the file : /home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/carbonapps/work/1425396583636WebShopOrderAdapterCA_1.0.0.car/ValidateIncomingRequest_1.0.0/ValidateIncomingRequest-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:199) ... 20 more Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Sequence Deployment from the file : /home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/carbonapps/work/1425396583636WebShopOrderAdapterCA_1.0.0.car/ValidateIncomingRequest_1.0.0/ValidateIncomingRequest-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:473) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeployer.java:80) at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.SequenceDeploymentInterceptor.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeploymentInterceptor.java:42) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:192) ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ValueFactory.isDynamicKey(ValueFactory.java:124) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ValueFactory.createValue(ValueFactory.java:59) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.InvokeMediatorFactory.buildParameters(InvokeMediatorFactory.java:77) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.InvokeMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(InvokeMediatorFactory.java:62) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:41) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:87) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeployer.java:55) ... 22 more
```

**Exception Image:**
[image]
**Problem:**

Anybody know any expected reason due to which it is making the CAR file faulty. I am not understanding the error.

Comment: Will you please copy that exception as it's and add the code tag rather than editing the exception traces.

Comment: I have pasted the exception as it is and also posted the image of exception from WSO2 ESB Management Console.

Comment: Seems like the issue with the alidateIncomingRequest-1.0.0.xml. Can you check it or posted in here.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I was calling a template inside that sequence and was not passing all the parameters. Once i did, it worked like a charm.

Comment: please mark the issue as answered if you have got this working